# Não consigo alterar propriedades usando css

Tags: html, css

Estou aprendendo desenvolvimento web e ao tentar fazer um teste simples não consegui alterar tamanho da fonte, cor de background e outras propriedades. Não entendi onde estou errando.

```css
#tabela{
 font-size: 64px;
 background-color: red;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Campanhas publicitárias</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div>
   <img src="imagens/capa.png">
  </div>

  <div>
   <tr id="tabela">
    <td>item1</td>
    <td>item2</td>
    <td>item4</td>
    <td>item5</td>
   </tr>

  </div>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o que estou fazendo errado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você declarou uma linha de uma tabela fora de uma tabela. Isso não é válido em HTML, mas o interpretador de HTML do seu navegador tenta corrigir erros automaticamente para manter a página e rodando, e como resultado a sua `tr` que contém o id responsável pelo estilo é apagada, deixando o elemento sem estilo.

Tudo que você precisa fazer é colocar sua `tr` dentro de uma `table`:

```
<table>
    <tr id="tabela">
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```